# How to modify ReadOnly values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this value `fetchOptions: Readonly<HttpFetchOptionsWithPath>` and I'd like to overwrite one of its properties. 
I've tried the following:

```
((fetchOptions as Writable<HttpFetchOptionsWithPath>).headers as Writable<any>) = {
    'new-value': '123',
    ...(fetchOptions.headers || {}),
  };
```

but still get an `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'headers' of object '#<Request>'` error.

The js code that gets executed looks like this:

`fetchOptions.headers = __assign({ 'new-value': '123' }, (fetchOptions.headers || {}));`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please if you could provide more code snippets I could help more anyway I answered based on what available in the question. hope it helps!

Comment: You can't, that's the point of making a property readonly.

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify the read-only values.. what you can do is cloning these object into new instance and continue using the new instance ...

```
Object.assign(newVariable, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldVariable)));
```

This also will do the job:

```
const newVariable={...oldVariable, propertyToModify:value}
```

Comment: Actually this answer is not incorrect but when the value of the property is a function this statement will not function well

Answer (score 1):

> **With this statement you can copy and overwrite properties**

```
var obj={...originalObj,[readOnlyProp:value]}
```